# Unable to add users from Keycloack on FreeIPA via LDAP although Keycloack host has permissions set in FreeIPA

Tags: ldap, freeipa, keycloak

I have the following setup:

- FreeIPA 4.8.7 via docker (freeipa/freeipa-server:centos-8)
- Keycloack 12.0.1
- The FreeIPA users are in `cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com`
- Keycloack DN: `krbprincipalname=ldap/keycloak.example.com@FREEIPA.EXAMPLE.COM,cn=services,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com`

I created a host account for keycloack via this script: https://gitlab.lindenaar.net/scripts/freeipa/tree/master#freeipa-service-passwordsh and was able to successfully pull the users from FreeIPA into keycloak.

In the FreeIPA web UI I added the "User Administrator" role to the keycloack host.

Now when I try to add a user in keycloak however I get the following error:

```
LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient 'add' privilege to add the entry 'uid=newuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com'.
]; remaining name 'uid=newuser,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com'
```

If I do `docker exec -it freeipa-server-container ipa host-show --all --raw keycloak.example.com` I get:

```
dn: fqdn=keycloak.example.com,cn=computers,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  fqdn: keycloak.example.com
  krbcanonicalname: host/keycloak.example.com@FREEIPA.EXAMPLE.COM
  krbprincipalname: host/keycloak.example.com@FREEIPA.EXAMPLE.COM
  krbprincipalname: keycloak@FREEIPA.EXAMPLE.COM
  has_password: FALSE
  has_keytab: FALSE
  managedby: fqdn=keycloak.example.com,cn=computers,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  cn: keycloak.example.com
  ipaUniqueID: 6dc12944-51b6-11eb-b243-0242ac110002
  krbPwdPolicyReference: cn=Default Host Password Policy,cn=computers,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  krbTicketFlags: 3145856
  managing: fqdn=keycloak.example.com,cn=computers,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberof: cn=User Administrator,cn=roles,cn=accounts,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=Stage User Administrators,cn=privileges,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Modify Users,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Manage User SSH Public Keys,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Read UPG Definition,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Modify Groups,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Add Users,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Undelete User,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Preserve User,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Modify Stage User,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Add Groups,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Read Stage User password,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Remove Users,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Remove Stage User,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Add User to default group,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Modify User RDN,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Read Stage Users,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Manage User Certificates,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Remove Groups,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Manage User Principals,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Read Radius Servers,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Read Preserved Users,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Read User Kerberos Login Attributes,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Modify Preserved Users,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Reset Preserved User password,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=Group Administrators,cn=privileges,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Modify Group Membership,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Add Stage User,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Modify External Group Membership,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Unlock User,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Remove preserved User,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=System: Change User password,cn=permissions,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  memberofindirect: cn=User Administrators,cn=privileges,cn=pbac,dc=freeipa,dc=example,dc=com
  objectClass: ipaobject
  objectClass: nshost
  objectClass: ipahost
  objectClass: pkiuser
  objectClass: ipaservice
  objectClass: krbprincipalaux
  objectClass: krbprincipal
  objectClass: ieee802device
  objectClass: ipasshhost
  objectClass: top
  objectClass: ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys
  objectClass: krbticketpolicyaux
  serverHostName: keycloak
```

What am I missing? I see there is a `cn=pbac` in that list but I don't know where that comes from and what it means. Is that why the permissions are not taking?

Answer (score 0):

I am using FreeIPA 4.11.0 and Keycloak 23.0.4. They are linked via LDAP. Originally, I had these same problems as you and I got further than you, but still struggle. I wanted to share what changes I have that made it actually add users to LDAP.

You should already have LDAP configured as a User Federation, but here's my config:

```
Connection: ldap://192.168.x.y
Bind type: simple
Bind DN: uid=keycloak,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=x,dc=y
Edit Mode: WRITABLE
Users DN: cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=x,dc=y
Username LDAP attribute: uid
RDN LDAP attribute: uid
UUID LDAP Attribute: ipaUniqueID
User object classes: top, inetOrgPerson, organizationalPerson
Import users: On
Sync Registrations: On
Enable the LDAPv3 password modify extended operation: Off
Validate password policy: On
Trust Email: On
```

In FreeIPA, my Keycloak user has a permission set that is dedicated to it with all of the user administrative privileges; but it never actually worked until I added my Keycloak user to the `admins` group. I don't know why it is required here.

A thing that then helped me was "User object classes" -- what happens here is Keycloak tries to add the user to LDAP with the User object classes you have marked here; then, it uses mappers to sync fields back to LDAP as part of that user. Each user object class has a specific requirement on which fields need to be sent back. This is where it gets very annoying. For example, you have to set mappers up that are going to send data back to LDAP. You may find yourself going attribute by attribute trying to get the minimums....

One you will need is `cn` and then you will have to force a default value like "New User" because you can't script together "firstName + lastName" to give a full name (I read that you can do scripts, but it requires plugins/extensions). Ultimately, I have like 19 mappers that range with user-attribute-ldap-mapper, to group-ldap-mapper, to role-ldap-mapper, to hardcoded-ldap-attribute-mapper. Some attributes to consider are userPassword, username, userCertificate, uidMapper, roleMapper, groupMapper (groupOfNames class)... but it ultimately relies on your environment.

Ultimately, I am adding these users to LDAP, but they are not reflected in the FreeIPA UI. That's because when you try to add user objects which seem to correlate with what a new FreeIPA-created user has, it requires even more attributes to be assumed and sent over. I have found users hiding in the backend; use `kinit admin` and `ldapsearch` to find any straggling accounts on your FreeIPA instance.